# Database Tables in Wordpress Theme

Tags: theme-development, database

I am creating some sliders type functionality for my wordpress theme and I thought that creating two seperate db tables like 'sliders' and 'slider_images' is a good idea.

My problem is that i don't know what is the best way to handle the creation of those tables. If it was a plugin, I would just do it on activation, but it is just some functionality as part of my theme and i haven't really found a hook that is executed once when the theme is activated.

If possible, i would like to not have to check the database for the existence of tables in every page refresh and create if not. Is there a way to do that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use separate database tables in a Theme, *especially* for creating custom content types. Use WordPress-core Custom Post Types.

Comment: oh, I see thanx !